# Pass Get Variables Using Header

Tags: javascript

i have a shadow box in my page , and im passing some values to it,

```
function edit(facility_group_id){
    Shadowbox.open({
        content:    'register_facility_form.php?facility_group_id=' + facility_group_id ,   
        player:     'iframe',
        height:     1150,
        width:      2200,
        options: {
            onClose:
            function() {
                top.location        = "index.php?page=backup_and_restore";
            }
        }
    });
};
```

if I want to pass another variable like below how can i do that in the content part,

```
function edit(facility_group_id,facility_name){
    Shadowbox.open({
     content:    'register_facility_form.php?facility_group_id=' + facility_group_id ,
```

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an ampersand between each query string variable:

```
function edit(facility_group_id,facility_name){
Shadowbox.open({
 content:    'register_facility_form.php?facility_group_id=' + facility_group_id + '&facility_name=' + facility_name ,
```